# Vuejs checkbox indeterminate status

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, status

I need little help. I have world regions list with countries inside:

```
{
    'North American Countries' : {
        'countries' : {
            'us' :   { 'name' : 'United States'  } ,
            'ca' : { 'name': 'Canada' }
            .
            .
            .
            .
        }
    },
     'European Countries' : {
         ......
     }
}
```

HTML:

```
            <ul v-for="(regionName, region) in regions">

                <li>
                    <label>{{ regionName }}</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" @change="toggleGroupActivation(regionName)">
                </li>

                <li v-for="country in region.countries">
                    <div>
                        <label for="country-{{ country.code }}">{{ country.name }}</label>
                        <input id="country-{{ country.code }}" type="checkbox" :disabled="!country.available" v-model="country.activated" @change="toggleCountryActivation(regionName, country)">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

And I try to build the list with checkboxes, where you can select countries. If check whole region's checkbox, automatically checked all countries in it region. If are checked only few countries in region(not all), need to display indeterminate checkbox status by region checkbox. How to handle it?

Comment: I use jQuery, find required checkbox element in DOM, and with .props() add indeterminate status. It's dirty way. looking for more elegant(vuejs) way

Comment: Can you provide HTML that shows how a checkbox in each of the states is specified?

Comment: Update details in question

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution to the Select All checkbox is to use a [computed with a setter](https://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter). When the box is checked, all the sub-boxes are checked (via the set function). When a sub-box changes, the Select All box value is re-evaluated (in the get function).

Here, we have a twist: if the sub-boxes are mixed, the Select All box should indicate that somehow. The approach is still to use a computed, but instead of just true and false values, it can return a third value.

There's no built-in way of representing a third value in a checkbox; I've chosen to replace it with a yin-yang emoji.

```js
const rawData = {
  'North American Countries': {
    'countries': {
      'us': {
        'name': 'United States'
      },
      'ca': {
        'name': 'Canada'
      }
    }
  },
  'European Countries': {
    countries: {}
  }
};

const countryComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '#country-template',
  props: ['country', 'activated'],
  data: () => ({ available: true })
});

const regionComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '#region-template',
  props: ['region-name', 'region'],
  data: function () {
    const result = {
      countriesActivated: {}
    };

    for (const c of Object.keys(this.region.countries)) {
      result.countriesActivated[c] = { activated: true };
    }
    return result;
  },
  components: {
    'country-c': countryComponent
  },
  computed: {
    activated: {
      get: function() {
        let trueCount = 0;
        let falseCount = 0;
        for (const cName of Object.keys(this.countriesActivated)) {
          if (this.countriesActivated[cName]) {
            ++trueCount;
          } else {
            ++falseCount;
          }
        }
        if (trueCount === 0) {
          return false;
        }
        if (falseCount === 0) {
          return true;
        }
        return 'mixed';
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        for (const cName of Object.keys(this.countriesActivated)) {
          this.countriesActivated[cName] = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    regions: rawData
  },
  components: {
    'region-c': regionComponent
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="region-template">
  <li>
    <label>{{ regionName }}</label>
    <input v-if="activated !== 'mixed'" type="checkbox" v-model="activated">
    <span v-else>☯</span>

    <ul>
      <country-c v-for="(countryName, country) in region.countries" :country="country" :activated.sync="countriesActivated[countryName]"></country-c>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
<template id="country-template">
  <li>
    <label for="country-{{ country.code }}">{{ country.name }}</label>
    <input id="country-{{ country.code }}" type="checkbox" :disabled="!available" v-model="activated">
  </li>
</template>
<ul>
  <region-c v-for="(regionName, region) in regions" :region-name="regionName" :region="region" :countriesActivated=""></region-c>
</ul>
```